# Lazy load image gallery

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, lazy-loading, imagelist

I receive an object from a service with an image and some detailed information.

There is a way to load the gallery using lazy load. I intend to load the images slowly as I scroll, instead of loading the images all at once.

Can someone help me?

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckdlsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of data; let  j = index;">
      <li class="mdc-image-list__item">
        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
            <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular, I have built a library to lazy load a gallery. You can use this library on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-opengallery there is a demo available. It's open source too, you can check the repo and adapt it to your needs. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll see if I can adapt and get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at what is called Intersection Obsever (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).
I would definitely suggest to use an external library, something like `lozad.js`.
See https://github.com/ApoorvSaxena/lozad.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use an intersector, follow an online example, but it didn't work, I always carried the entire object. I may have done something wrong

Comment: Let an external library to use it. Take a look at `lozad.js` by adding a class in the `img` tag you can easily make it. See the Lozad page examples. It's very neat and you don't have to reinvent anything.

Comment: I am having a problem to implement in component.ts. I have already installed a library and a reference, but I am not able to do the import or the component. Can you help me? I updated the link

Comment: I was able to implement without errors, but I don't know if it is working correctly, because it is loading everything and does not show any "blur" when loading

Comment: You might want to open the Network tab in the inspector. Check if the cache is disabled when the inspector is open and clean it. Then.... when you open your page you should only see, in the ispector, the images you have on your screen. See also on the bottom part of the inspector how many bytes did you transfer and check if they raise when you scroll the page. If you use chrome, you can perform a performance check, it will tell you if you are doing it correctly. It's called lighthouse or audit.

Comment: I tested it and in fact, it continues to load at the same time

Comment: Are you using src instead of data-src?

Comment: You have the same image, in order to test it you need to use different ones. When I wrote to clean the cache and do not use it when the inspector was open I meant exactly this case. If you have the same image there is no need to load it lazily.